# Android 7 service gpsupdate

Tags: java, android

I have a service class in java for android 7 which should submit the GPS location of the device. See below.

The problem that i have is that Android Studio throws an exeption like 'task is not yet complete'.

I also tried running it as a separate thread.

How to solve this?

```
protected void getLocation() {
    // Create the location request to start receiving updates
    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);

    // Create LocationSettingsRequest object using location request
    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
    builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
    LocationSettingsRequest locationSettingsRequest = builder.build();

    // Check whether location settings are satisfied
    // https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsClient
    SettingsClient settingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);
    settingsClient.checkLocationSettings(locationSettingsRequest);

    // new Google API SDK v11 uses getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
    fusedLocationClient = getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

    // Approach 1
    setGpsLocation(fusedLocationClient);

    // Approach 2
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                setGpsLocation(fusedLocationClient);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

}

```
private void setGpsLocation(FusedLocationProviderClient f) {
    Location location = f.getLastLocation().getResult();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("<Data>");
    sb.append(" <UserId>" + userId + "</UserId>");
    sb.append(" <Type>GpsLocation</Type>");
    sb.append(" <Longitude>" + location.getLongitude() + "</Longitude>");
    sb.append(" <Latitude>" + location.getLatitude() + "</Latitude>");
    sb.append(" <DateTime>" + sdf.format(new Date()) + "</DateTime>");
    sb.append("</Data>");

}
```

}

Comment: `getLastLocation` this is an async task. You must wait for it to complete before calling the result. Read the docs https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current

Answer (score 0):

The getLastLocation() method returns a Task object. A Task object represents an asynchronous operation (usually an operation to fetch some value, in this case a Location object). You retrieve the latitude and longitude of a location from the Location object. In rare cases when the location is not available, the Location object is null.

The Task class supplies methods for adding success and failure listeners. If the operation is successful, the success listener delivers the desired object. If the operation is unsuccessful, the failure listener delivers an Exception.

```
mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(
       new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
           @Override
           public void onSuccess(Location location) {
               if (location != null) {
                   mLastLocation = location;
               } 
           }
       });

mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnFailureListener(
       new OnFailureListener() {
           @Override
           public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
               Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: ", e.printStackTrace());

           }
       }
);
```